# Postgres Unique Constraint on two columns: Integer and Boolean

Tags: postgresql, constraints, unique

I would like to find a way to store multiple addresses for one subject in my database, with only one default address per subject.

To cut a long story short, lets say we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  active boolean NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

For each id in the table, there must be at most 1 true active value.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually you don't have to do *anything* since `id` being the primary key makes it unique so there *cannot* be two rows with the same ID.

Comment: If you don't want `id` as primary then you will need to write a trigger: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html but thats probably not what you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-partial.html) is what you want:

```
create unique index some_index on test (id) where active;
```

As @ThiefMaster states primary index should be removed.

Comment: Thanks. That is fine because my PK is the address PK in this table. This also works: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX some_index
  ON test
  USING btree
  (active, id)
  WHERE active;

Comment: You should notice that the only thing you have really changed in your query is adding active to index. While active is always true for all fields that a subject for indexing you just added some bloat.

Comment: PK is just a sum of UNIQUE and NOT NULL constraints.

Answer (score 4):

In this Question’s case it's not needed as explained previously.

But FYI, you *can* set constraints to 2 or more (non-PrimaryKey) columns with different types. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (integer_column, boolean_column);
```

For more info, see the Postgres doc for [Constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html), the "Unique Constraints" section. To quote:

> If a unique constraint refers to a group of columns, the columns are listed separated by commas…
>
> This specifies that the combination of values in the indicated columns is unique across the whole table, though any one of the columns need not be (and ordinarily isn't) unique.

**Note:**
A [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) sets an index built over a subset of a table, which has a completely different purpose.

Comment: I think with your solution he cant have multiple non active addresses.